# webrtc - video get blob, but it remain black

Tags: html, html5-video, webrtc

I run my webrtc code with chrome 21.

If I open two tabs in the same chrome, and then open page with webrtc code inside.
One tab is for sending video stream; one tab is for receiving video stream 
It works fine.

However, If I open page with two Incognito mode or two different chrome browser,
I can get the **sdp** and **candidate** information correctly. It seems that video can decode the information.

In remote video, I can see only [image]

Besides, it seems crash. I tried to click "close chrome" but useless.

Does anyone have any similar problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While testing **WebRTC**, I found that such condition occurs when we call `peerConnection.addStream(…)` in the **wrong** place ----

*You must remember that ordering highly matters in **WebRTC**!*

---

#### Updated at: 6:36 PM - Thursday, July 17, 2014 (UTC)

Blank video occurs in following cases:

1. You're using STUN whilst your SSL certificate is either expired or it has invalid entries.
2. You're using STUN however it is corporate firewall, or hospital network or private network which is blocking or hiding external ip addresses or some ports.
3. Both peers has invalid sendrecv/sendonly/recvonly pairs
4. Offerer didn't attach the stream or it is Firefox which fails in cases when user attached only audio stream however you're using `OfferToReceiveVideo:true`
5. You're checking for `HTMLMediaElement.HAVE_CURRENT_DATA` or `mediaElement.paused` or `mediaElement.currentTime` whilst it is android which has known issues regarding these properties.

### Solutions?

1. Use TURN from XirSys or [install your own](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/).
2. Make sure that you're using valid SSL certificate or use HTTP instead.
3. Make sure that offerer attached the stream; also make sure that `OfferToReceiveAudio`/`OfferToReceiveVideo` are used according to stream(s) attached.
4. Make sure that you didn't modify the SDP; also try to compare SDP between both peers and find-out mismatches.

Ordering of the code is, kind of rare-issues, nowadays, because we all know that `addStream` should be called before creating offer or answer; even for renegotiated sessions.

Try to use `chrome://webrtc-internals` and Firefox's `about:config` to see what's happening inside these browsers; and always use console-logs for `onIceConnectionStateChange` event which helps you check if ICE-Agent `failed` in the ICE-connectivity check process or...

Sometimes setting-remote-sdp for offerer too earlier, causes exceptions. Always use `onSdpError` both for `createOffer`/`createAnswer` and `setLocalDescription`/`setRemoteDescription` e.g.

`peer.setRemoteDescription(remoteSDP, onSdpSuccess, onSdpFailure);`

---

A few demos resources:

1. https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment / [Demos](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/)
2. https://github.com/mozilla/webrtc-landing

and https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html

Comment: The process is while creating offer --- you've to addStream right after creating PeerConnection ---- but when creating answer --- you must addStream after calling setRemoteDescription ---- I tested it; and it worked for me! --- It is just my personal experience!!!!

Comment: pc2.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc2.SDP_OFFER, new SessionDescription(sdp));

is this wrong ?

Comment: peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(peerConnection.SDP_OFFER, offer); --- peerConnection.addStream(yourCameraStream); ----- so the stream you'll attach for other peer will work fine!

Comment: I have this same issue, However the ordering appears to be correct and still no video stream is presented.  Has anybody managed to resolve this?

Comment: OfferToReceiveAudio and OfferToReceiveVideo constraints "must" be true for createOffer/createAnswer. "addStream" must be called before creating offer/answer sdp.

Comment: I have got the same problem, but can not resolve it. Could someone who got it to work make a list of the ordering on the one client sending the stream and the one receiving the stream? I do not see my mistake :(

Comment: @MuazKhan Thank you for the reply, but sadly I am still not able to locate my error. I tested a WebRTC Demo provided by http://www.esegece.com/ and everything works fine. I even looked through their js (sadly it is minified) to pick the same STUN server they do, but still black :/

Comment: Try any demo from https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment especially [video-conferencing](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/video-conferencing/) and [RTCMultiConnection demos](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/).

Last night I was testing "RTCMultiConnection-demo" with a friend, and it is appeared that both Google's and AnyFirewall's STUN failed because my friend was using corporate-network, however XirSys's STUN succeeded and STUN-connection was established. I thought that it'll use TURN, but it didn't. It was direct-p2p.

Comment: Please, how do you suggest to "compare SDP between both peers" - I should compare all fields in `sdpOffer` and `sdpAnswer` which I send to receive video?

Comment: Same black video comes in my case if local & remote are in local. Tried from two different system, for local and remote, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and I just resolved it by calling VideoElement.play() right after attaching the stream as the VideoElement.src

```
document.querySelector( "#video" ).src = window.URL.createObjectURL( remoteStream );
document.querySelector( "#video" ).play();
```

Don't wait for the loadedmetadata event because it doesn't seem to be triggered but the WebRTC stream.

Comment: <video autoplay src="" /> will play the video as soon there is e src added, e.g. your blob url. And for your selfView use <video autoplay muted src="" /> to prevent hearing yourself.