# webrtc - Getting video blob, screen black on Windows Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, chromium

The problem is when I share my screen from my laptop with Windows to the RPi the stream is black *(Chromium 48)* or the stream is invisible *(Chromium 49)*. There is always the **blob** of the video in the `<video>` tag.

Let me explain it, I am developing a Chrome Extension to share the desktop vía *WebRTC*. I need a signaling server that I developed with NodeJS and the Peer that recieve the stream is a webpage serve by the same server. The webpage is where we can see the video stream in a RPi with Chromium, 48 and 49. The client, who captures the screen, has the chrome-extension and the player are inside the same network.

The extension works almost everytime but I have some exceptions. In the following cases it works:

```
|  Pi Browser  | Client OS |   Client Browser   | Works? |
|:------------:|:---------:|:------------------:|:------:|
| Chromium 48  | Linux     | Chromium 50        |   YES  |
| Chromium 48  | Linux     | Chrome 50          |   YES  |
| Chromium 49  | Linux     | Chromium 50        |   YES  |
| Chromium 49  | Linux     | Chrome 50          |   YES  |
| Chromium 48  | Windows   | Chrome 49          |   NO   |
| Chromium 48  | Windows   | Chrome 50          |   NO   |
| Chromium 48  | Windows   | Chroma Canary (52) |   YES  |
| Chromium 49  | Windows   | Chrome 49          |   NO   |
| Chromium 49  | Windows   | Chrome 50          |   NO   |
| Chromium 49  | Windows   | Chrome Canary (52) |   YES  |
```

Then I tried using the Chromium 50 and Chrome 50 on my laptop with Linux as a player and works everytime. Maybe the fault is for Chromium on RPi?

Meanwhile I was looking for a solution I found this: [webrtc - video get blob, but it remain black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189109/webrtc-video-get-blob-but-it-remain-black). The case seems similar. I did what it says. Checked where is the `addStream`, Used the deprecated API of `setLocalDescription/setRemoteDescription(sdp, onsucc, onfail)`, always says it succeess. The answer has the `mandatory: { OfferToReceiveVideo: true, OfferToReceiveAudio: true}}` but there is no change. I don't know what to do now for solve this.

Are there some workaround for this? I need to make it work for Windows without Chrome Canary. Maybe some flag I did not see in Chrome for Windows.

Comment: I'm just here thinking and I thought is there a problem with the codecs? Because Chromium hasn't the propietary codecs? Source: https://www.chromium.org/audio-video

Comment: This might help to the viewer of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12232843

Comment: Did you ever figure out why you were getting the black video? I'm experiencing a similar problem with Chrome 64. It works fine on Linux, but I just see black on macOS and Windows.